# Adding Blogger template to predefined list

Tags: templates

I am working on updating a Blogger layout for a friend's website, and haven't had much luck in searching for this.

Essentially, I want to create the template and show them before pushing it live.  At present, there are lists of sample templates (Simple, Dynamic, etc), and I'd like to add mine as a clickable button for them to preview.

When I attempt to import it, it is automatically published as the live template...but I don't want it to be seen before they review it.  I want them to be able to switch between the current version and my version to see what is preferred.

Is this even possible? It would be extraordinarily straightforward in WordPress, but I've never used blogger before...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot add your custom template to the dashboard, you will have yo create another blog and show the template to your friend, there is no other way.

Comment: That's what I was afraid of.  Shame this functionality isn't available...kind of seems like a no-brainer.  Thanks!